# Validating hidden field data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user model that requires `city_id, state_id, and country_id`. Instead of asking the user each of these on their profile, I took the more modern way and added a location autocomplete. When the user selects an autocomplete option, I store the `city_id` in a hidden field on the form. When the form submits, I'd like to ensure this city is a valid city on my city table. As of right now, I have this logic in my User controller. I do something like this:

```
def update
    # I override the strong parameters here so I can add / remove them if I
    # need to.
    @user_params = user_params
    if @user_params[:city_id]
        @city = City.find_by id: @user_params[:city_id]
        if @city.present?
            @user_params[:city_id] = @city.id
            @user_params[:state_id] = @city.state.id
            @user_params[:country_id] = @city.country.id
        else
            # Here I'd like to tell the user they submitted an invalid location
            # rather than invalid city, state, country. I don't believe
            # I can add custom validation errors in the controller though.
        end
    end
    # Update the user, etc.
end
```

So I guess there's a couple questions (I'm fairly new to Rails):

1. Where should I put this logic for reusability?
2. Is this the correct approach for what I'm trying to accomplish?
3. How does one group validations like `city_id, state_id, country_id` into one validation like: Invalid location.

Comment: Why do you need the state and country to be set if you can get it through the city?

Comment: @japed Yeah I thought about that on the way to work today, I'll be removing those (state_id, country_id). The questions should still apply though.

Answer (score 0):

So with those removed, you just need to validate the presence of the city, rather than the city_id - http://railsguides.net/belongs-to-and-presence-validation-rule1/

```
class User
  validates :city, presence: { message: "Location is invalid" }
end
```

Comment: Right, now that would make sense. Thanks! Any ideas on the other questions? They were sort of the big ones.

Comment: Because it's now a model validation you can just do `if @user.update(user_params)`

Comment: So if someone modifies the hidden `city_id` field with an ID that isn't valid, the validation would pick that up? Would I not have to check if it's valid?

Comment: I only asking this because there might be a case where I just need to validate a field IF the user chooses to enter data. Otherwise, it's not required by the model.

Comment: A field not on the model?  I'd use an `attr_accessor` then add errors to the model in a custom `validate` method

Comment: Maybe I can look into that then. But for the first question, if someone modifies the hidden city_id field with an ID that isn't valid, would I not have to check if it's valid?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by invalid?  It'll check to see if a city with that id exists and fail validation if it doesn't

Comment: Oh ok, that's what I was asking, yeah. I just wanted to make sure a user couldn't add a random ID in the hidden field. I'll have to try it out.